# Excel formulation for addition based on value constarint

Tags: excel, math, excel-formula

> [image: Blockquote]

This is some random values I've inserted to check formula.
Basically I want P/L to be TOTAL EXITED - TOTAL INVESTED
However when I've not exited,P/L shows -(TOTAL INVESTED) as I'm using SUM(TOTAL EXITED,-TOTAL INVESTED).
Any formula to check P/L only in cases I've TOTAL EXITED greater than 0.

Thanks..!

Comment: Are you aware of the IF-function? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try an `IF` formula to check if TOTAL EXITED is greater than 0

`=IF(TOTAL EXITED>0,TOTAL EXITED - TOTAL INVESTED, 0)`